# Blender Arm Twists After Applying Automatic Weight Paint

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Upon finishing rigging my low poly model in Blender, I decided to parent the rig to the mesh and apply automatic weights. The head, spine, legs, and feet all work fine, however, the arm has an odd twist in it. I also noticed that the default pose position of the armature is different than that of the rest pose or edit mode positions of the armature. I've tried applying Alt G, Alt R, and Alt S but nothing changed, and both the odd position and twist remain. Is this an issue with my rig or topology, or will applying and adjusting weight paint manually solve the problem? This is my first time rigging a model in Blender so any help is highly appreciated.

Edit Mode/Rest Pose Position:
[image]

Default Pose Position with no transformations or rotations:
[image]

Arm twist in the mesh after applying automatic weights:
[image]

Edit: I made a comment of how I fixed this issue but TL;DR
Unparent the mesh and armature. Select all the bones in pose mode. f3 search Apply pose as rest pose. Parent them again and apply automatic weights and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 1):

After searching around some more I found a related post here:

[Parenting Armature to Mesh with Automatic Weights deforms Mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69934/parenting-armature-to-mesh-with-automatic-weights-deforms-mesh?rq=1)

My issue was that my Pose Position and Rest Position were different, as I showed above, however, I wasn't sure if this was normal or how to go about fixing it. I found from the other post that it's actually the reason for the mesh deforming and the fix is pretty simple. Selecting all of the bones in Pose Mode and pulling up the search bar with f3 you can type "Apply pose as rest pose", hit enter, and then parent the armature to the mesh and apply automatic weights and the issue with arm twisting is gone. I'm pretty new here but I think this post may be classified as a duplicate now but I found a lot of similar posts unanswered so hopefully, this is helpful to other beginners running into similar troubles.